# Deleting everything after the last comma SAS

Tags: sas, substr

I have an address field that has address similar to:

```
1 High Street, London, Uk, L1 6YR 
Flat 2, 35 Second Street, London,Greater London, L14 8FG
```

I would like to get rid of everything after the last comma so that I end up with:

```
   1 High Street, London, Uk
   Flat 2, 35 Second Street, London,Greater London
```

I tried to do this:

```
DATA WANT;
SET HAVE;
ADDRESS_NEW = SCAN(ADDRESS, -1, ",");
RUN;
```

But this just returns the post code:

```
L1 6YR
L14 8FG
```

Comment: Please also share any code you have tried and if you get any errors then please say what they are.

Comment: @Amir I've added in what I've already thought to try. I don't know what else to try so I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PRXCHANGE` to modify a text value meeting your desired criteria.  This example uses the regex pattern `s/,[^,]*$//` to replace the found end part with nothing.

```
data have;
input address $80.;
datalines; 
1 High Street, London, Uk, L1 6YR 
Flat 2, 35 Second Street, London,Greater London, L14 8FG
Argy Bargy Lane
London, Uk
run;

data want;
  set have;
  address = prxchange("s/,[^,]*$//", 1, address);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

FindC with the B option.

```
24   data _null_;
25      input address $80.;
26      put / address=;
27      l = findc(address,',','b');
28      if l then address = substrn(address,1,l-1);
29      put  (_all_)(=);
30      datalines;


address=1 High Street, London, Uk, L1 6YR
address=1 High Street, London, Uk l=26

address=Flat 2, 35 Second Street, London,Greater London, L14 8FG
address=Flat 2, 35 Second Street, London,Greater London l=48

address=Argy Bargy Lane
address=Argy Bargy Lane l=0

address=London, Uk
address=London l=7
```